# Snowflake correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've found other questions with similar issues, but the answers don't match my needs and I don't see how to adapt them. The problem, of course, is that Snowflake doesn't support most correlated subqueries and I don't know how to achieve what I want to do without one. Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

```
SELECT
   IH.ID
   , (SELECT "DESCRIPTION" 
      FROM DISPUTE_REASON 
      WHERE INVOICE_HEADER_ID = IH.ID 
      ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC LIMIT 1) DISPUTE_REASON
FROM
   INVOICE_HEADER IH
```

The key is I need to be able to get the most-recently-created record in the DISPUTE_REASON table within the scope of an invoice header ID. I've tried using a function to do it, but I get the same error, "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated". I've also tried using FIRST_VALUE with GROUP BY, but they don't play together.

Can anyone think of a way to do this without using a correlated subquery?

Comment: Is there any reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Comment: @forpas because it was the one I tried that worked

Comment: Do you mean that you did not try the other answers?

Comment: If you have a single value to want, the first_value/last_value is the cleanest solution, if you want many values from the sub-table, a row_number solution is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a window function like this:

```
SELECT IH.ID, dr."DESCRIPTION" as DISPUTE_REASON
FROM INVOICE_HEADER IH LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT dr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dr.INVOICE_HEADER_ID ORDER BY dr.CREATED_AT DESC) as seqnum
      FROM DISPUTE_REASON dr
     ) dr
     ON dr.INVOICE_HEADER_ID = IH.ID AND dr.seqnum = 1;
```

Snowflake also supports lateral joins, so I'm surprised your version doesn't work.  Try this:

```
SELECT IH.ID, dr."DESCRIPTION" as DISPUTE_REASON
FROM INVOICE_HEADER IH LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT dr.*
      FROM DISPUTE_REASON dr
      WHERE dr.INVOICE_HEADER_ID = IH.ID
      ORDER BY dr.CREATED_AT DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) dr;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the seq_num trick worked, although the lateral join didn't. It gives the same subquery not supported error.

Comment: @MikeCaputo . . . It seems very strange to me that Snowflake would support lateral joins but not one of their more common uses.  Oh well.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `LEFT` join of `INVOICE_HEADER` to `DISPUTE_REASONFIRST` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ih.ID, 
       FIRST_VALUE(dr.DESCRIPTION) OVER (PARTITION BY ih.ID ORDER BY dr.CREATED_AT DESC) DISPUTE_REASON
FROM INVOICE_HEADER ih LEFT JOIN DISPUTE_REASON dr
ON dr.INVOICE_HEADER_ID = ih.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variation of `ARRAY_AGG`, while ordering with a `WITHIN GROUP`, and then extracting the first element from the array:

```sql
SELECT
   IH.ID
   , (ARRAY_AGG(DR."DESCRIPTION") within group (ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC))[0] DISPUTE_REASON
FROM
   INVOICE_HEADER IH
JOIN DISPUTE_REASON DR
ON DR.INVOICE_HEADER_ID = IH.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

forpas's first_value is the cleanest solution for the problem you have stated. Gordon's solution is how you tackle it is you are wanting many values from that subtable.

Gordon's solution can also be written with a QUALIFY and thus be cleaner again.

```
SELECT IH.ID
    , dr."DESCRIPTION" as DISPUTE_REASON
FROM INVOICE_HEADER IH 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM DISPUTE_REASON 
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INVOICE_HEADER_ID ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC) = 1
) dr
    ON dr.INVOICE_HEADER_ID = IH.ID;
```